# change the default output format mongoose nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

my schema in node js

```
var itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({    
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  value: { type: String }  
});
```

while doing find, the following result comes,

`Item.find().exec(callback);`  gives result

```
[{"one":1},{"two":2},{"three":1},{"four":1}]
```

but i want the result like this,

```
[{"one":1,"two":2,"three":3,"four":4}]
```

Is there only way iterate and form the result ?

Please suggest me!

Comment: You're adding _name_ and _value_ to your Schema, but you're getting _one_, _two_, _three_ and _four_ back in the result?

Comment: i want to customize the output, in the find statement to exec(callback)

Comment: is there any way, after  exec(callback)  after i iterate and build the json

Comment: You can always update your result in JavaScript... There is a chance you can do it instantly in Mongo but then I need a lot more information like an input document and a desired output document.

Comment: if mongo means, how is it?

Comment: With an aggregate function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83245/discussion-between-thomasbormans-and-ramamoorthy-villi).